# Concatenar strings no arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Como eu posso concatenar duas ou mais strings utilizando a linguagem `C` com  Arduíno.

Estou seguindo vários exemplos que encontrei por aí, mas sempre me gera um erro. *"conversion from 'unsigned char' to 'String' is ambiguous"*

Estou usando o `.concat()`

```
void VuetifyDateTime(int hours,int minutes)
{
      String hourSt = String(hours);
      String minutesSt = String(minutes);
      
      String dateTime = hourSt.concat(minutesSt);
      
      TM1637(dateTime.toInt());
```

Comment: Esse tipo String é de uma biblioteca ou é um typedef seu?

Comment: É do próprio Arduíno. classe String

Comment: `hourSt.concat(String(minutes));` deve remover a ambiguidade. De acordo com a referência, essa função aceita parâmetros de tipo String. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/pt/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/concat/

Comment: Deu certo. Quer postar como resposta?

Comment: Não precisa, foi só um problema de type casting e isso é trivial. Acredito que o tipo `String` tenha algum operador que faz a conversão automática para `unsigned char` e como concat aceita muitos tipos diferentes, o compilador fica confuso com a ambiguidade. `std::string` é mais confiável.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito desta forma, lembre-se de fazer o free do ponteiro result

```
    const size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    const size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1); // +1 para o \0
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result + len1, s2, len2 + 1); // +1 para o \0
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer a concatenação de strings utilizando o operador "+", como no exemplo abaixo:

```
void VuetifyDateTime(int hours,int minutes)
{
  String hourSt = String(hours);
  String minutesSt = String(minutes);
  
  //Concatenação.
  String dateTime = hourSt + minutesSt;
  
  TM1637(dateTime.toInt());
}
```